# Initialize Array to Default Value (Except where Specified) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I want to declare a large array with every value set to DEFAULT_VALUE in initialization except three values at places throughout the array.

Writing `int array[2048] = { DEFAULT_VALUE };`

will fill the whole array with the default, and

`int array[2048] = { [4] = VALUE_1, [123] = VALUE_2, [2047] = VALUE_3 };`

will set specific indexes and the rest to zero (it is in global space), but how can I initialize the array to have specific values AND my own default value? Can I write my own initialization routine?

Speed is a priority here btw.

Comment: In case you didn't know, the second is a compiler-specific extension and not standard C++.

Comment: "*Writing `int array[2048] = { DEFAULT_VALUE };` will fill the whole array with the default*" - no, it won't. It will fill in only the 1st element with `DEFAULT_VALUE`, the rest of the elements will be value-initialized to 0 instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a dynamic memory allocation, I would just use a `std::vector` like

```
std::vector<int> array(2048, DEFAULT_VALUE);
array[4] = VALUE_1;
array[123] = VALUE_2;
array[2047] = VALUE_3;
```

Which optimizes quite well in this [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/D74G-T)

Answer (score 0):

As with so many optimization questions, profile your code before optimizing. I highly doubt that initializing this array could be a bottleneck in any scenario.

That being said, there is no clean syntax for this. Just set the values from a reasonable initialization routine yourself. This is what the compiler would do anyway.

Consider also using `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem by mixing c and c++ in my program. I used "extern C" where appropriate. Using C I can write:

```
int array[256] = { [0 ... 255] = DEFAULT_VALUE, [4] = VALUE_1 };
```

to set the whole array to my own default value except where specified otherwise. I like clean code so switching to C for this one feature worked for me. Vectors and the heap are not options, as this code will run on an embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::valarray`:

```
std::valarray<int> v(DEFAULT_VALUE, 2048);
v[std::_Sizarray{ 4, 123, 2034 }] = { VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3 };
```